# Clean string with just specified value PHP?

Tags: string, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I have this in PHP

```
$string="Thisissomekindofstringiwantthislolipop";
```

I want new string like this

```
$string="iwantthis";
```

But i have more string similar

```
$string1="Thisissomekindofstrigqqqqqqqqqkokiki";
```

And new string

```
 $string1="qqqqqqqqq";
```

The value of letters at beggining is always the same, and i always need new string with same letters count, is posible to do that?

Txanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cut the string you should take a look on [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).
You can then cut the unneeded parts:

```
<?php
$string="Thisissomekindofstringiwantthislolipop";
echo substr($string, 22, 9); // returns 'iwantthis'
?>
```

Update because of your comment:

You can also split a string by a delimiter (here: with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)). E.g.

```
<?php
$string = "vimeo.com/24076588";
$parts = explode("/", $string);
echo $parts[1]; // prints 24076588
?>
```

Or even nicer. Just extracting the numeric id from the URL with a regular expression using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
<?php
$string = "http://vimeo.com/24076588";
preg_match_all('/[\d]+/i',$string, $result); 
print_r($result);  
?>
```

This prints out

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24076588
        )

)
```

Comment: $link = substr($link, 20, 9);

Comment: ok, thanks, but if some casess something like this http://vimeo.com/24076588  how to take only numbers not link i want only this 24076588, but the problem is that number can be 10 letter 12 i dont know how much, i only want to remove http://vimeo.com/ that is always constant, txANKS

Comment: Ok, for the Vimeo example a code snippet with a regular expression. See above :)

Comment: Txanks mate, but, strane thig happens when inserting in mysql, with this i got empty?? I dont know why? if ($video==1)
{
$parts = explode("/", $link);
$link= $parts[1];
}  Only got when insert into blank field in table?

Comment: Just check what it's in $parts using e.g. print_r($parts). The explode example with position [1] of course just only works, if the slash '/' is at the correct position. Use the regular expression to be more safe.

Comment: Array ( [0] => http: [1] => [2] => vimeo.com [3] => 24076588 )

Comment: as you can see it's at position 3 so $parts[3] will give the id.

Comment: Again great txanks, can i do little help more, i have <span>Koliko</span> i want new $string="Koliko";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15824/discussion-between-miomir-dancevic-and-happy-coding)